# Rendering async objects in angular2 templates

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a template:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>{{user && user.displayName}}</h1>
    <p>How is your day, today??</p>
    <mood-meter [current]="user && user.currentMood"
                (onChange)="moodChanged(value)"></mood-meter>
</div>
```

How can I rid off all those && operators? User is set when observable is resolved.

Async pipe doesn't work well with objects. How do you handle it?

Comment: never seen it with it with &&.. you could use the elvis operator (?).. so: `{{user?.displayName}}`
And i'm not rly sure what you mean with "Async pipe doesn't work well with objects.".. Got an example?

Comment: Great answer (elvis operator). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using observable to be resolved just replace the below lines

```
<h1>{{user && user.displayName}}</h1>
```

`<mood-meter [current]="user && user.currentMood"(onChange)="moodChanged(value)"></mood-meter>`

Replace with

```
 <h1>{{user && user?.displayName}}</h1>

<mood-meter [current]="user && user?.currentMood"(onChange)="moodChanged(value)"></mood-meter>
```

I just put '?' after user object, it will keep updating for object change data asynchronously.